# Avoid pytest hanging when libpython crashes

Tags: python, c, pytest

I'm using pytest with pytest-xdist to test some C code (via python bindings).

When a C program calls `abort()` this segfaults libpython.
This is fine for a single process run (it exits with 134), but when I'm using `-n[something]` then pytest just hangs and never returns.

I was hoping that `--max-worker-restart 0` would do the trick, but alas no.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to (ideally) treat this crash as a failed test or (less ideal but still better than what I currently have) to just exit with an error code and not hang?

Comment: *When a C program calls `abort()` ...*  You've just discovered **another** reason using `abort()` of any form as an error "handler" is a really bad idea.

Comment: Haha yes, I realized it’s worth looking at alternatives there, true.

Comment: Doing a `raise()` from C and catching it in pytest sort of works, but then I have another issue with detecting at runtime whether the C code is called from pytest or not and do `raise()` vs `abort()` depending on which.